# Parse IOS query that returns matched values for a given key where values are contained in an array

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, arrays, parse-platform

I want to know if there is a way to get the values that matched from a query like the following:

```
[query whereKey:@"interests" containedIn: @[@"reading",@"writing",@"typing"]];
```

Now say parse has a columned named interests that contains a row with the values: ["reading","typing"] and another ["reading","typing","running"] and another ["writing","running"]

Is there a way to know which values the array matched on?

The containedIn array that I will supply will be dynamically created from a list of interests the user selects.

And so It would be helpful to know which values the query matched on, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to scan the result set returned from the query and do this yourself.

Here's an example using Cloud Code which given params such as

```
@{ @"interests": @[ @"reading",@"writing",@"typing" ] }
```

would return results of the form:

```
@[ @{ @"user": PFUser, @"matchingInterests": @[ @"reading" ] }, ... ]
```

Cloud Code function:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

Parse.Cloud.define("searchInterests", function (request, response) {
  var interests = request.params.interests;
  if (!interests) {
    response.error('interests is required');
    return;
  }

  new Parse.Query(Parse.User)
  .containedIn('interests', interests)
  .limit(1000)
  .find()
  .then(function (users) {
    var results = _.map(users, function (user) {
      return {
        user: user,
        matchingInterests: _.filter(user.get('interests'), function (userInterest) {
          return _.contains(interests, userInterest); 
        });
      };  
    });

    response.success(results);
  }, function (err) {
    response.error(err.message);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there would be something built in to make this even easier than it already is. In any case it was straightforward enough thank you for the direction.